# LDAP Spring security login-processing-url 302 error

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I have a web application that connects to an LDAP server, everything works fine until now create a new branch in LDAP and processing url I get "Error 302 Moved Temporarily". I had never been anything like this, I have the configuration of the LDAP server in a .properties.

The strange thing is that I work very well for a configuration, but now that you create a new branch for testing, I get this error.

Nose that will be what makes this happen, be if I can help.

These are my files.

With this configuration works

```
#Properties LDAP Server
ldap.context.initialContextFactory  = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.context.providerUrl            = ldap://192.168.0.31:389/dc=store,dc=web,dc=ap
ldap.context.securityAuthentication = simple
ldap.context.securityPrincipal      = cn=admin,dc=web,dc=ap
ldap.context.securityCredentials    = adm5569
```

With this configuration I send the HTTP Error 302 Moved Temporarily

```
#Properties LDAP Server
ldap.context.initialContextFactory  = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.context.providerUrl            = ldap://192.168.0.31:389/dc=store2,dc=web,dc=ap
ldap.context.securityAuthentication = simple
ldap.context.securityPrincipal      = cn=admin,dc=web,dc=ap
ldap.context.securityCredentials    = adm5569
```

this is my security.xml file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/webapp/ViewChangePassword" security="none" /> 
    <http pattern="/webapp/LogonForm" security="none" />


    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/Home" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/ListStore" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/CheckStoreJson" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/ViewChangePassword" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/ChangePassword" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webapp/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login login-page="/webapp/LogonForm" default-target-url="/webapp/Home" authentication-failure-url="/webapp/LogonForm?code=1" login-processing-url="/webapp/LogOn" />
        <logout logout-url="/webapp/LogOut" logout-success-url="/webapp/LogonForm?code=2" /> 
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://${ldap.server.ip}:${ldap.server.port}/${ldap.server.root}"/>


    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator" id="ldapBindAuthenticator" >
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
        <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch" >
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="ou=usuarios"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="ldapServer" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" >
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.springrole.rdn}"/>
        <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="${ldap.springrole.attribute}"/>
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="${ldap.springrole.prefix}"/>
        <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(objectClass=organizationalRole)"/>
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapBindAuthenticator"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="cl.bbr.security.UserLdapMapper" id="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper">
        <beans:property name="template"         ref="ldapTemplate"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

EDIT (1) 29-10-2014

302 Moved Temporarily The error appears in the Debug console google Chrome, attempting to log in through the login, redirects me to the login error page and Debug Console google I figure that the URL to process authentication with the Security is temporarily moved.

Help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get "Error 302 Moved Temporarily"? Where do you see it? Is there a stacktrace or debug log output associated with it? When do you get it - i.e. what request are you making? Is there a URL that you are being redirected to? Are you saying that authentication fails or something else? Please edit your question to include this information. I'd guess your authentication is just failing so you are being redirected to the login error URL.

Comment: Enable debug logging and have a look at the server log contents which is where the actual issue occurs. You won't be able to understand server errors just by looking at the browser console. A 302 response code is just a redirect, so almost certainly your authentication is failing because of the LDAP changes and you are just being sent back to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to give permissions to the user in the branch, to read, modify and delete the branch I'm going